# combining and filtering array of objects into a single object in javaScript

Tags: javascript

```js
let myCurrentData = [
  {
    _id: "D01",
    name: "Lunetts",
    profession: "shop",
  },
  {
    _id: "D02",
    name: "Glasses",
    profession: "keeper",
  },
  {
    _id: "D03",
    name: "Auros",
    profession: "UiiSii",
  },
];
```

Above is my myCurrentData, I want to convert this array into a final object like the following

```js
 let myFinalData = {
 D01: "Lunetts",
  D02: "Glasses",
  D03: "Auros"
}
```

i just want to use the values of _id and name

Comment: What have you tried so far? `Object.fromEntries` and `myCurrentData.map` should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const myCurrentData = [
  {
    _id: "D01",
    name: "Lunetts",
    profession: "shop",
  },
  {
    _id: "D02",
    name: "Glasses",
    profession: "keeper",
  },
  {
    _id: "D03",
    name: "Auros",
    profession: "UiiSii",
  },
];

const finalObject = myCurrentData
  .map((eachObject) => {
    const { profession, name, _id } = eachObject;
    return {
      [_id]: name,
    };
  })
  .reduce((prev, current) => {
    return {
      ...prev,
      ...current,
    };
  }, {});

console.log("finalObject is", finalObject);
```

Hope it works!

Comment: Reaching for `map` and then `reduce` is making the code way too complicated when there is [a far simpler alternative](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...of_statement).

Answer (score 1):

[Use a simple loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...of_statement) to create a new object.

```js
const data=[{_id:"D01",name:"Lunetts",profession:"shop"},{_id:"D02",name:"Glasses",profession:"keeper"},{_id:"D03",name:"Auros",profession:"UiiSii"}];

const out = {};

for (const obj of data) {
  out[obj._id] = obj.name;
}

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using reduce and returning an object from it:

```
const myObj=  myCurrentData.reduce((acc,curr)=> {
    return {...acc, [curr._id]:curr.name}
  
}, {})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take advantages of the Object.entries method combined with a forEach loop to get the properties name and values and add it to your previously declare myFinalData Object. Something like this could be what you are looking for. Hope it helps, bud.

```js
const myCurrentData = [
  {
    _id: "D01",
    name: "Lunetts",
    profession: "shop",
  },
  {
    _id: "D02",
    name: "Glasses",
    profession: "keeper",
  },
  {
    _id: "D03",
    name: "Auros",
    profession: "UiiSii",
  },
];


 const myFinalData = {}
Object.entries(myCurrentData).forEach(([k,v]) => { myFinalData[v['_id']] = v['name']})

console.log(myFinalData);
```